# ATmega32U4: enabling interrupts hangs

Tags: c, microcontroller, interrupt, avr

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>

void delay() {
    volatile uint16_t i;
    for (i=1e6; i; i--);
}

int main(void) {
    DDRB = 255;
    /* sei(); */
    while (1) {
        PORTB ^= 1;
        delay();
   }
}
```

The above program blinks an LED.  With `sei();` uncommented it doesn't.  I haven't enabled any interrupt sources, the datasheet says they're all off by default, and while the bootloader (Caterina) does use TIMER1_COMPA it turns it off again before running my code.

It would seem it can't possibly be calling an undefined interrupt handler.  But I'm perplexed why else it would not get as far as blinking.

What's going on here?

Comment: Do you have a debugger?

Comment: I have an LED (two, actually). Maybe I could get a serial link up if I tried. But for now that's it.

Comment: Either the bootloader messes up the interrupts, or maybe the watchdog is configured to automatically start in interrupt mode (see fuses).

Comment: Side-note: initializing uint16_t variable to 1e6 seems interesting.

Comment: From avr-libc docs: "
sei()
Enables interrupts by setting the global interrupt mask. This function actually compiles into a single line of assembly, so there is no function call overhead. However, the macro also implies a memory barrier which can cause additional loss of optimization.
" So besides enabling interrupts, generated code may also differ otherwise. May we see generated assembly listing for both cases?

Comment: By the way, the `delay()` looks a little 'fragile', empty-looping over a local variable.

Comment: @teroi Since there are no (global) non-volatile variables, there's nothing that memory barrier would do to the generated assembler code.

Comment: @JimmyB: you're right.

Comment: The code you've posted here is not the cause of the problem.  You need to look at (or post here for us to) the boot loader to see what is is doing...

Comment: @teroi: disassemblies at 
https://sphere.chronosempire.org.uk/~HEx/tmp/dis.good and https://sphere.chronosempire.org.uk/~HEx/tmp/dis.bad . Also as you might've guessed I was just incrementing the exponent until the flashing was slow enough to see; didn't spot the overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the bootloader[1] left the USB controller enabled and generating interrupts.

Adding an empty `ISR(USB_GEN_vect)` fixed the hang but produced massive slowdown of the blinking, presumably due to the ISR not actually doing anything about the conditions that caused the interrupts in the first place, thus being called repeatedly.
Adding `USBCON = 0;` before `sei();` worked properly.

[1] Caterina, as mentioned. Code for the bootloader is at https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/hardware/arduino/avr/bootloaders/caterina/

Comment: This is the correct answer for combination of MCU and bootloader. Fixed issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

If the LED remains On, it's probably the Watch Dog Timer interrupt. your micro is restarted before blinking happens. As I recall, it might be enabled/disabled using a fuse-bit.

Comment: Adding `MCUSR &= ~(1 << WDRF);` and/or `wdt_disable()` changes nothing; I already tried that. Nor does adding `wdt_reset()` in the main loop have any effect.
avrdude reports the fuses as `E:CB, H:D8, L:FF` which AFAICT does not indicate the watchdog is always on.